# Get data from build.gradle after constants have already been replaced

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, react-native, android-build

I would like to parse a `build.gradle` file and get (*for example*) the `minSdkVersion` version; is there a way to fill in the constants or get a processed version of the file in which they are already filled in?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = I_AM_A_CONSTANT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until something better comes along, I am doing the following:

1. Build the application with `./gradlew clean app:assembleDebug`.
2. `output.json` is created in `android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug`, it is a `json` file that includes at least some of what I need:
   a. `packageId` (the application package `com.example`).
   b. `minSdkVersion`.

Note: you can find the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the same directory, I found it easier to work with a `json` file.